# jQuery not behaving as expected in reference to clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that I grab the content of and swap for an input, I then want to user to be able to click on the input (to enter text as normal), but if they click anywhere else to swap it back to the text.

However the click event seems to fire even the very first time the user clicks anywhere on the page. My code is below, have I misunderstood something?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#thingy").css('cursor', 'pointer');
   $("#thingy").one("click", function() { 
     var element = $(this);
     element.css('cursor', 'auto');
     element.css('display', 'inline-block');
     element.fadeOut(100, function(){element.html('<input type="text" size="25" value="' + element.text() + '" style="width:' + element.width() + 'px;height:' + element.height() + 'px;border:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;">')}).fadeIn(100);
     $("#thingy").click(function() {
       return false;
     });    
     $(document).click(function() {
         alert("You clicked off the text-box");
         element.html(element.children('input:text').val());
     });
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it alerts even the first time is the *first* `click` handler (the `.one()` doesn't itself `return false;` or `.stopPropgaton()`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#thingy").css('cursor', 'pointer');
   $("#thingy").one("click", function() { 
     var element = $(this);
     element.css('cursor', 'auto');
     element.css('display', 'inline-block');
     element.fadeOut(100, function(){element.html('<input type="text" size="25" value="' + element.text() + '" style="width:' + element.width() + 'px;height:' + element.height() + 'px;border:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;">')}).fadeIn(100);
     $("#thingy").click(function() {
       return false;
     });    
     $(document).click(function() {
         alert("You clicked off the text-box");
         element.html(element.children('input:text').val());
     });
     return false;
  }); 
}); ​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vJRe9/2/).

A better approach would be to use the `blur` event instead, replacing this:

```
     $("#thingy").click(function() {
       return false;
     });    
     $(document).click(function() {
         alert("You clicked off the text-box");
         element.html(element.children('input:text').val());
     });
     return false;
```

With this:

```
     $(element).delegate("input", "blur", function() {
       element.html(element.children('input:text').val());
     });
```

[You can try that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vJRe9/1/).

Comment: With the second version I am getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in chrome, looked it up and seems to be with bad naming, but I can't see what would be causing this?

Comment: @Pez - Did you copy/paste from the jsfiddle? Sometimes a weird character that *seems* like a space slips in there, try deleting all spacing and see if it fixes it (the space/weird character is *probably* on the end).

Comment: Nope I used the code posted here at stackoverflow... hmm... I will play around and see if I can fix it!